# How can I disable all animation in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app that run on web and desktop. Is there a way I can disable all animations (e.g. scroll animations and routing to new page animations) from a single place in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to disable Transition animations and Slide Animations on FLutter, but this a requested feature right now due to Flutter Web being a thing now.

As a workaround, you can use the transition-duration property of PageRouteBuilder Widget.

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, 
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => Page1(),
        transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
    ),
);
```

Although you will have to implement this on every Route Navigation you perform.

Comment: can you please put link of the feature request here? just want to check update

Answer (score 0):

for disable transfer animation on whole flutter app you can use custom pageTransitionsTheme in ThemeData. Example:

```
class AppThemes {
  const AppThemes._();

  static ThemeData light() {
    return ThemeData(
      pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
        builders: {
          TargetPlatform.android: NoAnimationPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          TargetPlatform.iOS: NoAnimationPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NoAnimationPageTransitionsBuilder extends PageTransitionsBuilder {
  @override
  Widget buildTransitions<T>(
      PageRoute<T> route,
      BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child,
      ) {
    // No animation, simply return the child
    return child;
  }
}
```